# React native ScrollView disable one direction on condition

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-scrollview

is it possible to scroll only to one direction?
I have a function that detects the direction the user is a scroll.

But I can't figure out how can I set a flag, that if the user doesn't answer the question it will not allow him to scroll right only left?

thank you

Comment: directionalLockEnabled - Will this be useful for you? https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview#directionallockenabled - Only on iOS

Answer (score 3):

I have created a small example, where only scrolling to the right is allowed. Of course this example can be adapted to allow left scrolling in specific conditions. In the code, I marked the position where to add such a condition.

### **Demo**

[image]

### **Explanation**

The example consists of two main parts.

1. Detecting the scroll direction and disable scroll if necessary
2. Enabling the scroll again

**Detecting scroll direction**

See code comments for explanation

```
handleScroll(event){
      // WIDTH originates from Dimensions.get('screen').width
      const endOfView = event.nativeEvent.contentSize.width - WIDTH; 
      const positionX = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x; 
      const positionY = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y; 

      // check if we are scrolling left, also detect if we are at the end of the scrollview 
      // MARKED: check other conditions here to allow scrolling again
      if(this.state.lastPositionX > positionX && endOfView > positionX){
        // we are scrolling left, disable scroll, reset the current position
        this.setState({ lastPositionX: positionX, lastPositionY: positionY, allowScroll: false });
        // scroll back to last valid position. Important! Otherwise users may be able to scroll left
        this._scrollview.scrollTo({x: this.state.lastPositionX, y: this.state.lastPositionY});
        //call the timer to enable scroll again 
        this.callTimer();
      }else{
        // we are scrolling right, everthing is fine
        this.setState({ lastPositionX: positionX, lastPositionY: positionY });
      }
    }
```

**Enabling scroll again:**

We are making use of a timer to enable scroll again after a specified amount of time.

```
timerFn() {
  // clear the timer again, otherwise the timer will fire over and over again 
  clearInterval(this.state.timer);
  //enable scroll and reset timer 
  this.setState({allowScroll: true, timer: null });

}
callTimer() {
  if (this.state.timer == null ){ 
    // no timer is available, we create a new one. Maybe you have to fine tune the duration 
    let timer = setInterval(() => this.timerFn(), 1000);
    this.setState({timer});
  }
}
```

**Render:**

```
  <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
   <ScrollView
   horizontal
   scrollEventThrottle={15}
   scrollEnabled={this.state.allowScroll}
   onScroll={(event) => this.handleScroll(event)}
   ref={view => this._scrollview = view}
   >
     <View style={{width: WIDTH, backgroundColor: 'red'}} />
     <View style={{width: WIDTH, backgroundColor: 'green'}} />
     <View style={{width: WIDTH, backgroundColor: 'blue'}} />
   </ScrollView>
  </SafeAreaView>
```

### **Working Example**

https://snack.expo.io/rJAamRC2E

Answer (score 1):

You can use `react-native-directed-scrollview` package

Package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-directed-scrollview

This package has `scrollTo({x: 100, y: 100, animated: true})` method.
if you restrict x-axis coordinate to your conditions, it will be ok.

So try something like this,

```
if(isAnswered == false){
  scrollTo({x: /*x-axis position*/, y: /*y-axis position*/, animated: true})
}
```

note: you can pass `false` to `animated` parameter. It is optional.

Comment: no need to use an additional package. The [scrollTo](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview#scrollto) function is available for the standard `ScrollView`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who wants a fixed-height container with hidden content but need the `RefreshControl` functionality of a `ScrollView`, what i did was used a `ScrollView` but fixed its height.

When i want to show other content i animate the height/opacity of each content block to give the effect of scrolling.

```js
<ScrollView
    refreshControl={...}
    style={{ height: contentBlockHeight, overflow: 'hidden' }}
    contentContainerStyle={{ height: contentBlockHeight, overflow: 'hidden' }}
>
...
</ScrollView>
```